# Does anybody know how to program the Luxeed LED keyboards directly?

Tags: service, keyboard, driver

I have a Luxeed, either the U5 or the RaMa series (not sure which, these people don't give you a lot to go on).  I want to program the LEDs directly, but I have no idea how.  Their software isn't that intuitive and seems limited anyway (though it's hard to tell, it being so unintuitive and all).  Ideally it would be in Python (or possibly .net, since it should be a Windows service).  Anybody have any idea how I would do this?  Or where any specs are?  Thanks.

Comment: Since you're asking about a specific piece of hardware, and you don't know the details about the programming that needs to be done, I think you'll have better luck asking this at `superuser.com`. If this isn't urgent, you can just wait for a little while; I expect this question will be automatically moved to Super User for you soon.

Answer (score 0):

From here http://luxeed.com/files/8012/8538/3827/comparison_chart_en.jpg, it seems that if you have a U5 you are in bad luck as it does not seem to be able to interact with the host computer. If you have a rama or U7 maybe the best way to start is by looking to other implementations available in other O.S. .e.g.: kurtstephens.com/luxeed

Comment: thanks! and yes i do have a rama, found out after i posted that. will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've just bought a luxceed U7 (says model on the underside of the keyboard).

The Function Keys (F1-F8) represents each of the colors:

```
F1(R) == Red
F2(Y) == Yellow
F3(G) == Green
..
```

### To set the colors:

1. Press [Luxceed] Button
2. Press a function key, eg F3 for green.
3. The colored LED to the very right of the keyboard should go green.
4. Every key on the keyboard you now press will turn Green (unless its already coloured)
5. Pick a new color, eg F1 for red, what you press will now turn Red
6. Press [Luxceed] button again to turn off color setting mode (LED to right should go off).

### How to save a pattern/design/color layout:

1. Make a design as above by setting the colors.
2. Your keyboard can save a few different 'presets', my U7 stores four; P1, P2, P3, P4.
3. Hold down the [luxceed] key + P1 will save your current design over preset 'P1'.
4. Press say 'P2' to move off of your preset and over to preset 'P2'. Then press P1 to go back.

#### Do the presets stay saved? YES

For my U7, I was able to unplug the keyboard (kept it unplugged for a minute) then plugged it back in and it retained the presets I had in memory. I read somewhere that the keyboards did not save the presets when unplugged, but so far the save worked for me.